# What does ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError in Rails mean in my case?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, model

[image]             [image]

I have two Postgres tables that look like above.

`amount_availables` belongs to `facilities` as shown below:

```rb
class AmountAvailable < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :sequence_number
  belongs_to :facility

  validates :facility, :presence => true
```

When I run a complex query that joins these 2 tables, I get the below error (and this error is not consistent):

```rb
  ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError (missing attribute: facility_id):
```

**Generated SQL:**

This is the SQL that's generated:

```
 SELECT "as_of_date", "entity", "facility", "financial_institution", "amount_availables"."amount_available", "amount_availables"."comments", "amount_availables"."last_updated_on", "amount_availables"."last_updated_by" FROM "amount_availables" INNER JOIN "sequence_numbers" ON "sequence_numbers"."sequence_number" = "amount_availables"."sequence_number_id" INNER JOIN "facilities" ON "facilities"."facility_id" = "amount_availables"."facility_id" WHERE (sequence_numbers.as_of_date >= '10/01/2019' and sequence_numbers.as_of_date <= '12/24/2019' AND facilities.entity in ('3C7','HOLD CO','PCM','PC-M','PFSI','PLS','PMIT','POP','QRS','TAG','TRS')) ORDER BY last_updated_on desc
```

**NOTE:**
And until last week, I remember I was getting this error inconsistently (it occurred a LOT of times but not ALL the time! But this week I seem to get it pretty much all the time. And this SQL runs just fine on Postgres client against the same database that my Rails app is using).

Does this error mean there should be a column named `facility_id` in `facilities` table?

What should I do on my Rails code to fix this?

I even tried renaming the `id` column in `facilities` table to `facility_id` using the Rails migration code below:

**Approach 1 - Rails Migration Fix**

```rb
class ModifyFacilitiesPkColumnName < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
        rename_column :facilities, :id, :facility_id
    end
end
```

But I am still getting the same error even after the above approach (I DID run `rake db:migrate` and I can see in my `postgres client` that the `id` column in `facilites` HAS changed to `facility_id`).

What does this error mean precisely, and how do I fix this?

Comment: You don't need to run the last migration. It was fine earlier. Also can you share what query are you trying to run?

Comment: I've added SQL to my original question (pls refer 'GENERATED SQL' and 'NOTE:' in my original question)

Comment: Also add the rails activerecord query you have written.

Comment: This is how I construct the query in my Rails code : `AmountAvailable.joins(:sequence_number, :facility).where("sequence_numbers.as_of_date >= ? and sequence_numbers.as_of_date <= ? AND facilities.entity in (?)", $search_start_date, $search_end_date, all_entities).select(:as_of_date, :entity,  :facility, :financial_institution, :amount_available, :comments, :last_updated_on, :last_updated_by).order('last_updated_on desc')`

Answer (score 0):

Your Inner Join seems to be incorrect:

> `SELECT * FROM "amount_availables" 
>   INNER JOIN "sequence_numbers" ON "sequence_numbers"."sequence_number" = "amount_availables"."sequence_number_id" 
>   INNER JOIN "facilities" ON "facilities"."facility_id" = "amount_availables"."facility_id" 
>   WHERE (sequence_numbers.as_of_date >= '10/01/2019' and sequence_numbers.as_of_date <= '12/24/2019' AND facilities.entity in ('3C7','HOLD CO','PCM','PC-M','PFSI','PLS','PMIT','POP','QRS','TAG','TRS')) ORDER BY last_updated_on desc`

Instead it should be:

```
INNER JOIN "facilities" ON "facilities"."id" = "amount_availables"."facility_id"
```

It should work.

Comment: It used to be what you just said - but i changed the column name from `facilities.id` in the table to `facilities.facility_id` to see if that'd fix my issue.

So I get the same error with the join you have suggested as well!!

Comment: You don't need to do that. As i said, it was fine earlier. Go back to earlier version. Don't over complicate things. `facilities_id` in `facilities` table doesn't make sense.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion (but you could see why I did the name change - the error says `Missing attribute facility_id` :) ) and I browsed through a few more stackoverflow articles regarding this same error - I came across suggestions that there should be a column name that's the same as the missing attribute name given in the error)

Comment: But like I said, even with the column name as just `facility.id` in the table, i get the `EXACT SAME error`. Pls help! I have posted the code showing how I construct my query in my Rails code to your question in the previous section